# Typescript: Cannot write file '/xxx/products.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, turborepo

I have a Turborepo (not sure if that is relevant), that has a ts project as a package.

No matter what I try, I keep getting the same error for each file in the package project.

`Cannot write file '/xxx/products.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file`

Here is my base.json ts.config:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

And here is the ts.config inside the package:

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./build"]
}
```

And here are the important part of the package.json

```
"main": "./build/index.js",
"source": "./src/index.ts",
"types": "./build/index.d.ts",
"files": [
  "build/**"
],  
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "dev": "tsc -w",
  "lint": "TIMING=1 eslint \"src/**/*.ts*\"",
  "lint:fix": "TIMING=1 eslint \"src/**/*.ts*\" --fix",
  "test": "jest --passWithNoTests",
  "type-check": "tsc --pretty --noEmit"
},
```

So the errors come every time I run `npm run dev` on the project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

/Peter